# Can't link two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-150

I'm sure this is something ridiculously simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Every time I try running this script, I get error number 150. I know that this is a foreign key issue. My other tables are fine and link to the projectregister table with no problems, but for some reason nothing wants to link to the userchar table.

I'm running this on a college server, so I cant try show engine innoDB status.
Any ideas what's wrong here?
Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `userchar` (
  `userid` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `charname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `charstats` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`charname`),
  CONSTRAINT `userchar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `projectregister` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `notes` (
  `userid` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `charname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `usernote` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`charname`,`usernote`),
  CONSTRAINT `notes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `projectregister` (`userid`),
foreign key (charname) references userchar(charname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What is the exact error, post it in your question

Comment: Wouldn't a foreign key need to reference the whole key, not just part of it?  `userchar`'s key has two columns.

Comment: Sorry! Whole error is Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'myschema.notes' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key must reference a unique value - be it a primary key or a plain old unique index.

Here, you are attempting to make `notes.userid` reference `projectregister.userid`. However, `projectregister.userid` is not a unique value - only the combination of `projectregister.userid` and `projectregister.charname` is unique.

You should either change the primary key or the foreign key definitions so that their column lists match.